# Keep user logged- in in multiple tabs

Tags: reactjs, authentication, local-storage

The login functionality of my react application works, but when the application is opened in multiple tabs it asks for login again. I need the users to stay logged-in in all the tabs the user has opened in a specific browser. Also need the user to get signed out if the user signs out from any one of the tabs in a browser

I have set a local storage item user, and check it before logging in. For signout, the same storage gets cleared out.login details is a object which has the following items : accountName, email, displayName, accessToken and refreshToken

```
interface IUser {
    accountName: string,
    email: string,
    displayName: string,
    accessToken: string,
    refreshToken: string,
}
 
const cuser: IUser = {
                accountName: loginDetails?.accountName,
                email: loginDetails?.email,
                displayName: loginDetails?.displayName,
                accessToken: loginDetails?.accessToken,
                refreshToken: loginDetails?.refreshToken
            }
localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(cuser));
let userInfo:any = localStorage.getItem("user");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BrodcastChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel), here is an example using my library [sysend.js](https://github.com/jcubic/sysend.js) and custom hook, but you can do the same with native BroadcastChannel but sysend also works for older browser that doesn't support BroadcastChannel.

```
const useAutoLogin = (user, onAuth) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        sysend.on('autologin_syn', () => {
            if (user) {
                sysend.broadcast('autologin_ack', user);
            }
        });
        sysend.on('autologin_ack', (newUser) => {
            if (newUser && !user) {
                onAuth(newUser);
            }
        })
        sysend.broadcast('autologin_syn');
        return () => {
            sysend.off('autologin_ack');
            sysend.off('autologin_syn');
        };
    }, [user]);
}


const App = () => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState('');
    useAutoLogin(user, setUser);
    return (
        <>
            <div>{user ? `Welcome ${user}` : 'React'}</div>
            <button onClick={setUser('demo')}>login</button>
        </>
    );
}
```

Here is a [working demo](https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/yLQVgqd?editors=0010).

The code works like this, when opening the page you send message to all other tabs if any of is not logged in. If any of the tab is logged in, it send authentication data back.

You can also do it the other way around, when the user has multiple tabs open and she log in to one of them you broadcast login info to another tab. This one is actually simpler because you only send one event.

Instead of a string user can be an object that contains a username, email, and the authentication token.

And you can do the same on logout, but this is left as an exercise to the reader.